# How to point my node.js app to a non existing domain

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have an app running on a server where I access using the servers ip. But now I need to have a subdomain configured in order to make an external API work but I have no clue of how achieve it.

Now I access to my server using IP -> XX.XXX.XXX.XXX:3000

And I need to change it for something like -> myapp.companyname.com

Comment: Please [edit] your question to explain your API's requirement a bit more thoroughly.

Comment: use ```Nginx``` or another reverse proxy http web server to achieve that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution I needed was modifying the file hosts from -> system32/divers/etc/hosts and adding there the configuration relative to the ip - domain relation I was lookin for.

Answer (score 0):

You don’t, because the Internet doesn’t work that way.

You create the subdomain by configuring the DNS server for the domain to point that subdomain at the IP address.

If you want to change the port number (from the default of 80 to 3000) without putting it in the URL itself, then you need to change the Node.js program or put a proxy server in front of it.

Answer (score 0):

This is indeed a notorious problem with distributed web development. Presumably your API requires you to register your own hostname in some sort of allow-list, and then checks incoming requests for matches to that allow-list. (Why? Cybercreeps.)

You need to find out the IP address of your development machine (not `127.0.0.1`, that's the loopback IP and every machine has it). It's OK if your development machine's address is on a private network, like '192.168.0.20`for example. Give the command`ifconfig`and look for the address (it's`ipconfig` on Windows).

You then need to put that IP address into a DNS server.

Here's a free way to do that.

1. Create a FreeDNS account by visiting https://freedns.afraid.org/
2. Click on Subdomains.
3. Click the Add link.
4. Create a subdomain hostname under one of FreeDNS's public domains.  Maybe javier.ortega.mooo.com is a good choice
5. Put your machine's IP address into it.

Then, use https://javier.ortega.mooo.com:3000 to hit your development machine's nodejs app.

You can pay FreeDNS to register your own domain name and use that if you prefer.